# Как во время Insert select вставить id в другую таблицу

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO location_address (Adr_Line1, Adr_Line2, Adr_City, Adr_State, Adr_Zip)
SELECT Org_Address1, Org_Address2, Org_City, Org_State, Org_Zip FROM organization
```

Есть такой запрос, нужно после добавления каждой записи обновить в organization поле Org_Address соответствующим id из location_address

Результат

```
ALTER TABLE location_address ADD Adr_Migration_Org_Id INT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE organization ADD Org_Address INT NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO location_address (Adr_Line1, Adr_Line2, Adr_City, Adr_State, Adr_Zip, Adr_Migration_Org_Id)
SELECT Org_Address1, Org_Address2, Org_City, Org_State, Org_Zip, Org_Id FROM organization;

UPDATE organization
INNER JOIN location_address ON Adr_Migration_Org_Id = Org_Id
SET Org_Address = Adr_Id;

ALTER TABLE location_address DROP Adr_Migration_Org_Id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql и без триггера? Тогда только вторым запросом (ну или хранимкой) и при этом надо как-то сопоставить данные. Судя по названиям колонок, уникального индекса там нет.

Тогда могу предложить такое: добавляете в таблицу `location_address` ещё одно поле, например, `original_migration_id`, куда копировать первичный ключ таблицы-источника.

```
INSERT INTO location_address (Adr_Line1, Adr_Line2, Adr_City, Adr_State, Adr_Zip, original_migration_id)
SELECT Org_Address1, Org_Address2, Org_City, Org_State, Org_Zip, id 
    FROM organization;

UPDATE organization 
    JOIN location_address ON organization.id = location_address.original_migration_id
    SET Org_Address = location_address.id;
```

Если это разовая миграция, то поле `original_migration_id` теперь можно удалить.

Comment: вот это интересно сейчас попробую

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать триггер в базе MySql и настроить его таким образом чтобы при записи в одну таблицу осуществлялась запись в другую таблицу

Пример триггера:

```
AFTER INSERT ON `trigger_cart_items` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO trigger_cart_log (cart_id, item_id) VALUES (NEW.cart_id, NEW.item_id); END
```

Comment: триггер хорошо было бы но запрещено скорее всего =) это миграция